# Set new coefficients in sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I can construct a sparse matrix (csr for example) the following way:

```
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
```

This would be the easiest and most natural way considering the input data I have.

Now, the `data` might change, while structural info `row` and `col` stays the same.

**How can I set new `data` efficiently without repeating the whole construction process?**

(I expect that I must somehow optain a linear index map from `data` into the internal matrix storage, but I don't see whether that is offered at all.)

Comment: Is `col` always sorted within rows?  Check `has_sorted_indices`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign to the `.data` -

```
sparse_matrix.data = new_data[np.lexsort([col, row])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [109]: row = np.array([2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
     ...: col = np.array([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1])
     ...: data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
     ...: mat1 = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
     ...: 

In [110]: mat1.toarray()
Out[110]: 
array([[2, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [5, 6, 1]])

In [111]: new_data = np.array([23,90,45,67,21,99])

In [112]: mat1.data = new_data[np.lexsort([col, row])]

In [113]: mat1.toarray()
Out[113]: 
array([[90,  0, 45],
       [ 0,  0, 67],
       [21, 99, 23]])
```

We can replace `np.lexsort([col, row])` with `np.ravel_multi_index((row, col), mat1.shape).argsort()` if that's any better on performance.

Comment: But that will only work, if the input `data` has the same order as the internal `mat1.data` will have, right? So I need to guarantee that `row`, `col` and `data` are in the same order as the internal representation. It won't work, for example, if the input data is last-row-first.

Comment: @Michael Can we use `row` and `col` that was used at the first creation of the matrix for setting in the new_data?

Comment: Yes, those are still available. But I do not see how they should help, since the internal order of `mat.data` will depend in a non-trivial fashion and depending on the matrix format choosen. (I'm currently more thinking about setting 1, 2, 3, 4, ... as data upon construction and then deriving an index map from `mat.data`.)

Comment: @Michael Well, we need `row, col` to maintain the data format. A matrix won't know how the data was assigned originally, it only holds info about the rows, cols and their respective values. As such it doesn't have the information as to the fact that first of data : `data[0]` were from `(row[0],col[0])` which was `(2,2)` or something else.

Comment: The construction process will transform the input `data` into an internal flat `data` array depending on the matrix format (csc, csr, ...). Basically it would be possible to store the flat map from input `data` to internal `data` to facilitate quick reassignment of new coefficients without repeating the full construction process (for csr from row+col coords probably expensive). But it seems that numpy does not maintain such an index, but it's not too difficult to emulate though.

Comment: @Michael As posted `np.lexsort([col, row])` could be the reassignment index array that could be re-used.

Comment: Only under the assumption that coefficients are ordered first by column and then by row, which is not true for most sparse matrix formats.

Comment: @Michael Well, it computes the linear index equivalents (Row major mode) and gets the order based on it. I would think sparse matrices would follow that same model, just like NumPy arrays.

Comment: You need to understand the internal representation(s) to replace the `data` values directly. `coo` values may be in any order. `csr` will be sorted by row, but sorting within rows is optional (see its methods). `csr.sort_indices`, `has_sorted_indices`

Answer (score 0):

Often when making a sparse `coo` matrix this way, its attributes are just the input arrays.

```
In [241]: Mo = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3,3))
In [242]: Mo.data
Out[242]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [243]: Mo.row
Out[243]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
In [244]: Mo.col
Out[244]: array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
In [245]: id(Mo.col), id(col)       # ids match
Out[245]: (2851595992, 2851595992)
```

When converted to `csr` (or calling `csr_matrix`), all three are transformed.  This is done in compiled code.  Duplicate coordinates are summed (as documented).  Note also the new dtypes:

```
In [246]: Mr = Mo.tocsr()
In [247]: Mr.data
Out[247]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
In [248]: Mr.indices
Out[248]: array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [249]: Mr.indptr
Out[249]: array([0, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
```

The `coo` values can be in any order; the `csr` ones are sorted.  In your example this did not change the order (`indptr` replaces the `row` with a condensed form).

You can check the `csr` format with:

```
In [266]: Mr.has_canonical_format
Out[266]: True
In [267]: Mr.has_sorted_indices
Out[267]: True
```

If these aren't true it is possible to restore them with `Mr.sort_indices`.

I don't know what operations can mess up the order.  I'm pretty sure that the construction you use produces a canonical matrix.

I noticed that `Mr.copy` uses

```
def _with_data(self,data,copy=True):
    """Returns a matrix with the same sparsity structure as self,
    but with different data.  By default the structure arrays
    (i.e. .indptr and .indices) are copied.
    """
    if copy:
        return self.__class__((data,self.indices.copy(),self.indptr.copy()),
                               shape=self.shape,dtype=data.dtype)
    else:
        return self.__class__((data,self.indices,self.indptr),
                               shape=self.shape,dtype=data.dtype)
```

I wouldn't put too much effort into avoiding copies and new matrices.  Err on the side of safety rather than speed.  Keep in mind that `sparse` makes new matrices all the time, such as when doing `Mr[1,:]` or when doing math.  For certain repeated operations it may be worth your time to do things 'in-place', but don't try to do that routinely.

You might also find the code of `sparse.bmat` instructive.  It builds a new matrix from smaller ones.  Note how it combines the `coo` attributes into a new big set.

---

`lil` is also row oriented:

```
In [256]: Ml = Mo.tolil()
In [257]: Ml.data
Out[257]: array([[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
In [258]: Ml.rows
Out[258]: array([[0, 2], [2], [0, 1, 2]], dtype=object)
```